# Mongoose waiting for find to finish before saving

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to save a new document into MongoDB that has references to another collection so to get all the ObjectIds of the references I use find to get them before saving. I need to wait for the find to complete before continuing but I can't get it working. I think it has something to do with promises but I couldn't figure it out. I have an example below if I didn't explain this clearly. Any help would be appreciated!

Person Schema

```
const personSchema = new Schema(
    {
        name: { type: String, required: true },
        fruits: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Fruit' }]
    }
)
```

Fruit Schema

```
const fruitSchema = new Schema(
    {
        name: { type: String, unique: true, required: true },
    }
)
```

Add Code

```
router.route('/add').post((req, res) => {
   const name = req.body.name;
   let fruits = [];

   Fruit.find({ name: { $in: req.body.fruits }}, (err, foundFruits) => {
       if (err) res.send(err)
       foundFruits.forEach(fruit => {
            fruits.push(fruit._id);
       });
   });

   const newPerson = new Person({ name, fruits });
   newPerson.save()
       .then(() => res.json('Person added')
       .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err));
}
```

Example:
I want to add a person called "Bob" with references to "banana" and "apple" (assume already added in the DB) so I make a POST request with the body as...

```
{
    "name": "Bob",
    "fruits": ["banana", "apple"]
}
```

After I added it, when I check my DB, the entry is there but the "fruits" has an empty array instead of the references to "banana" and "apple".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the callback from the `find` method takes times to execute, by then the rest of your code finishes running. What you want to do is wait on the promise so the code executes as expected:

```
router.route('/add').post(async (req, res) => {
    const name = req.body.name;
    let fruits = [];

    let foundFruits = await Fruit.find({ name: { $in: req.body.fruits }});
    foundFruits.forEach(fruit => {
        fruits.push(fruit._id);
    });
    
    const newPerson = new Person({ name, fruits });
    newPerson.save()
        .then(() => res.json('Person added')
            .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err));
}
```

Because you're only using the `_id` of the fruits this can be done more elegantly using [distinct](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/):

```
router.route('/add').post(async (req, res) => {
    const name = req.body.name;

    let fruits = await Fruit.distinct("_id", { name: { $in: req.body.fruits }});
    const newPerson = new Person({ name, fruits });
    newPerson.save()
        .then(() => res.json('Person added')
            .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err));
}
```

Comment: Ahh I'll read more about distinct, never knew about it. Thanks a lot!